# Есть плагин (или wp-func решение) на WordPress для WooСommerce, позволяющий отфильтровать клиентов по количеству заказов?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте, мне как-то нужно нужны вывести клиентов в админке WooCommerce, которые сделали например 5 заказов ? Есть ли плагины или решения, как это сделать ? Лучше конечно плагин...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть плагин [WooCommerce Loyal Customers](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-loyal-customer/). Попробуйте его.

Comment: Супер! Очень долго искал, спасибо Вам большое!